# Error: Cannot enqueue Handshake after already enqueuing a Handshake from nodejs application

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am querying a table every 5 seconds and displaying to the user. I am using mysql 8. and application is nodejs.

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: xxxxxx,
  database: "test"
});


app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
  con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
     con.query(" select * fron table1; ",function (err, result, fields) {
if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
        if (result.length > 0) {
        res.send(result);
      } else {
        res.send({});
          }
  });

  });
```

when I call the fuction again its giving error.
Its because I see as I am not closing the connection. If I try to close the connection than also its not working.
I tried con.close().
is there a way I can get ride of this

Answer (score 0):

I think use pooling is the best way, I've fixed this error by using connection pool  and removing `.connect()` and `.end()`, using `.release`
instead, For example:

```
var pool        = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 10, // default = 10
    host            : 'localhost',
    user            : 'root',
    password        : '******',
    database        : 'test'
});

router.get('/users', function (req, res) {
    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM table1", function (err, rows) {
            connection.release();
            if (err) throw err;

            console.log(rows.length);
            res.send(JSON.stringify(rows));
        });
    });
});
```